# Reports only shows number of sub sites

Tags: web-analytics

1. I recreated a web analytic service because it quit working for months. Before recreating I went through all the blogs, msdn etc to get it fixed. Made sure permissions, all the timer jobs, checked logs (sp uls, windows, sql). I did not find anything so I created a brand new web analytic with brand new databases (staging and reporting)
2. Now the sites are only showing number of subsites. It does not show any other traffic reports.
3. under CA - monitoring > diag > everything is checked

Category    Metrics Value (Current) Value (Previous)    Trend
Traffic
    Total Number of Page Views  0   0   -
    Average Number of Page Views per Day    0   0   -
    Total Number of Daily Unique Visitors   0   0   -
    Average Number of Unique Visitors per Day   0   0   -
    Total Number of Referrers   0   0   -
    Average Number of Referrers per Day 0   0   -
Inventory
    Total Number of Sites   5   0

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: OMG. I think this is 7th post on this topic. Can't believe there are no solutions to issue. I did some online search and seems like you have taken all the actions possible to fix this issue. I would really like (someone from the admin team) look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the SharePoint Tracing Services (found under windows services) was using active directory log in. It needs to Local System login. Changed it to local system waited a day and boom the reports start to show numbers.